# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './model' PYTHON

Tags: python-3.x, permission-denied

Im following a tutorial from youtube on using torch library to build an AI that plays snake, a part of thr program makes a directory and saves a file inside of it, but i keep getting this error PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './model', iv'e read a lot of stuff on the internet about how to solve it but i just can't understand some of it and other stuff dosen't work, here is the relevant code:

````
        model_folder_path = './model'
        if not os.path.exists(model_folder_path):
            os.makedirs(model_folder_path)
        
        file_name = os.path.join(model_folder_path)
        torch.save(self.state_dict(), file_name)

    def load(self, file_name='model.pth'):
        model_folder_path = './model'
        file_name = os.path.join(model_folder_path, file_name)

        if os.path.isfile(file_name):
            self.load_state_dict(torch.load(file_name))
            self.eval()
            print ('Loading existing state dict.')
            return True
        
        print ('No existing state dict found. Starting from scratch.')
        return False```

does anyone know what is going on and how to solve it? Thanks a lot!!
````

Comment: Having a similar problem. Do you have a solution yet?

Comment: Yeah iv'e fixed it by changing the location of the folder, honestly i have no clue why that fixed the issue, hope it helps!